# Showing that $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu} = 1/\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite measures on the measurable space $(X,\mathcal A)$ which have the same null sets. Show that there exists a measurable function $f$ such that $0 < f < \infty$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\nu$-a.e. and for all $A \in \mathcal A$ one has
>
> $$ \nu(A) = \int_A f d\mu \quad \text{and} \quad \mu(A) = \int_A \frac{1}{f} d\nu. $$

My approach is to define $f = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ (applying the Radon-Nikodym theorem) and show that the second equality also holds. Showing the almost-everywhere-requirements is trivial.

I am able to prove this when $f$ is a simple function, but I run into trouble when I try to extend this argument. I tried to do this by writing $f$ as the limit of a sequence of increasing simple positive functions $f_k$, defining $\nu_k(A) = \int_A f_k d\mu$, and then showing that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \int_A \frac{1}{f_k} d\nu_k = \mu(A)$. I also showed that $\nu(A) = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\nu_k(A)$. However, I was unable to relate $\int_A \frac{1}{f} d\nu$ to these limits.

This is a practice question for an exam, so I'm not looking for complete answers, but I would really appreciate it if someone pointed me in the right direction. Is this the correct approach, or am I overlooking a much simpler argument?

Comment: just apply the Radon-Nikodym theorem, by noting that $\nu \ll \mu$.

Comment: @Solitary My question is, how do I get from there to the second equality?

Comment: Do you know [The Radon-Nikodym Chain Rule](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/the-radon-nikodym-chain-rule/)?

Comment: @MarcusM I wasn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know from Radon-Nikodym that there exists a nonnegative measurable function $g$ with the property that $$\mu(A) = \int_A g \, d\nu$$ for every measurable set $A$. Consequently $$\int \phi \, d\mu = \int \phi\, g \, d\nu$$ for every nonnegative simple function $\phi$, and by taking monotone limits you have $$\nu(A) = \int_A f \, d\mu = \int_A fg \,d\nu$$ for any measurable set $A$. Can you show that $fg = 1$ $\nu$-almost everywhere from here?

Comment: Yes, that does the trick, thank you! And it is certainly much more elegant than what I was attempting to do :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Since $\nu$ and $\mu$ have the same null sets, $\mu \ll \nu$, by R-N theorem, there exists $f$ with required properties such that
$$\nu(A) = \int_A f d \mu.$$
Therefore $d\nu = f d \mu$
Now evaluate $\int_A \frac{1}{f} d \nu$ as follows
$$\int_A \frac{1}{f} d \nu = \int_A \frac{1}{f} f d\mu = \int_A d\mu = \mu(A).$$

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the fact that, if $f = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$, one could replace $d\nu$ by $fd\mu$ in integrals, which is why I accepted the other answer.